# Inconsistent variable pass from express to jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm playing with Node.js, Express, Jade and MongoDB. I met a weird problem about rendering. I passed the variable "users" which is returned from db query like below and I'm pretty sure it's correct:

```
userProvider.findByIds(ids, function(error, users) {
  res.render('index', { users: users }); // This users here has all documents founded by Ids.
});
```

And in the Jade template file index.jade there is a loop:

```
- each user in users //-This users here has only one document after I added a new user
```

It does not work after I added a new user every time. It only shows one user which is the latest added user. But if I restart Node.js, it works correct and shows every user included the latest one.

I guess there is some cache issue with such things. Any idea about this?

Comment: You'll need to post the content of 'users' for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I just use users as example. It doesn't matter what kind of content it has, I think. For example, before render, I checked the length of users is 5. But in jade, the length of users is 1. This only happens after I added a new document.

Comment: Well, there isn't enough information here to provide an answer. In my experience, the tools you're using shouldn't have any problem passing values, be they scalars, arrays or objects. How are you "adding a document" to users? Via Mongo? Where are you calling res.render()? From within the handler you pass to Mongo?

Comment: Just updated the question. Hope it's more understandable now. This is the first question I asked here, :p.

Comment: Is your query throwing an `error`? Also, how are you adding a new users?

Comment: There is no error at all. And the query always return the correct result. Finally, it turns out to be a really weird bug. After I just changed the parameter name from "users" to any other name but not same as the value name, it's fixed. Not sure if it's a bug in Jade when rendering the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this is something like what your code looks like:

```
ul
  - each user in users
    li user.name
```

The issue with this is the dash character (`-`) at the start of the line with `each` in it.  The dash will translate the rest of the line into [unbuffered code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code), but `each` is not code.

The reason one user is rendered probably has to do with how jade/pug processes that line, I'd bet it takes the first one into memory but fails to process the loop.

Anyway, this is the correct syntax to loop through the users array:

```
ul
  each user in users
    li user.name
```